# Cleveref does not change its string even after changing minted's listing environment caption name

Tags: cross-referencing, captions, minted, cleveref

I am using the `minted` package's `listing` environment to typeset MATLAB source code.

As explained in the `minted` manual, I have used the `\SetupFloatingEnvironment{listing}{name=Program code}` option to change the caption title from the default `listing` to `Program code`. This succesfully updates the caption. However, when cross-referencing the source code in text, `cleveref` still uses the word `listing`.

Here is a `MWE`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[newfloat=true]{minted}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[nameinlink]{cleveref}
\SetupFloatingEnvironment{listing}{name=Program code}

\begin{document}

The code for computing mass-energy relationship is given in~\cref{code:massenergy}.

\begin{listing}
    \begin{minted}[autogobble,frame=single]{matlab}
    clear; close all; clc;
    e = m*c^2;
    \end{minted}
    \caption{Mass-Energy Relationship}
    \label{code:massenergy}
\end{listing}

\end{document}
```

The following is the output produced

[image: Wrong cross-refence string by cleveref for minted source code]

**How can I get `cleveref` to produce the expected cross-reference string in text?**

Comment: Add `\crefname{listing}{Program code}{Program codes}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `newfloat` package doesn't pass the new name to `cleveref`; you also need the plural form anyway.

Add

```
\crefname{listing}{Program code}{Program codes}
```

after the `\SetupFloatingEnvironment` line.

You can avoid code duplication by doing

```
\crefname{listing}{\listingname}{\listingname s}
```

Comment: Is there a way to define the desired caption name __only once__ in the document (perhaps as a variable?) and have both ```minted``` and ```cleveref``` pick it up automatically?

Comment: @Krishna Somewhat possible. See edit.

Comment: Upvoted. Almost there. But this results in capitalisation of the reference, i.e. we get a sentence like "the source code listing is given in Program code 1.1".  Is this acceptable typographic convention? the lower-case ```\cref``` usage should result in lower-cased referencing right? The ```\MakeLowercase``` construct is not working for me and results in an undefined reference ```?```. Any thoughts on how to fix this?

Comment: I figured it out. The trick is to use ```MakeLowercase``` right where ```crefname``` gets defined and not in the body of the document. So, the solution is ```\crefname{listing}{\MakeLowercase{\listingname}}{\MakeLowercase{\listingname s}}```